# PhpDocumentor 2 stucked while 'Transform analyzed project into artifacts'

Tags: phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I just started using PhpDocumentor 2. Everything seems to works and all the files are processed but when it reaches this 'Transform analyzed project into artifacts' it gets stucked for hours and never finishes it.

I was wondering if anybody had this issue before, it would be awesome if you can point me out to the right direction to fix it

Thanks!

Comment: I have been experiencing the same thing lately.

Comment: How much CPU is this using?  How many SLOC?  Mine's been running for two days now, but it's pegged the CPU the whole time (it's a very large project).

Answer (score 0):

phpDocumentor has a mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phpdocumentor and issues can be logged at https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues. You may want to bring this problem to either of those places.